# How do you tell the Apache Arrow Format Version for a given Library Version?

Tags: apache-arrow

Apache Arrow in their documentation list that each release has two versions, a Library Version and a Format Version: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Versioning.html

It appears that over the last year there have been 4 Library Versions, but it's hard to tell if the format version has changed in any of these Library Versions. Is there a way to tell what the Format Version is for a given Library Version?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, I do not see a way to determine the format version programmatically.  This seems like a good idea.  I have opened [ARROW-12594](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-12594).

The latest format version is also listed on the [specification page](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html).

Since the latest version is 1.0.0 you can safely assume that all Arrow versions >= 1.0.0 and <= 6.0.0 are compiled against format version 1.0.0